# React: componentWillUpdate

Tags: reactjs

Can somebody explain what really happens i the next context:

Let's assume i have an App component (parent) , and some children components let's say Index, Search, About and these 3 have their children.

What happen's when I call componentWillUpdate in App Component ... , the new state/ props will come but what will happen inside the leafs (children ), will they rerender themself ?

And let's say I overwrite something i DOM in this componentWillUpdate in App, and I'll the same thing in DOM in a leaf component in componentDidMount or componentWillMount... which value will be the last ?

Comment: I suggest you read through the documentation on lifecycle methods (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#lifecycle-methods).  I think it is explained pretty well there.  In general you want to avoid changing the DOM yourself, but rather let React  render your DOM based off changes in state whenever possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First at all, you shouldn't call `componentWillUpdate` manually. It is called by React if as part of it's lifecycle.

According to [comment in ReactCompositeComponent.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/renderers/shared/reconciler/ReactCompositeComponent.js#L49-L74) this is what hapens during update phase:

```
Update Phases:
        - componentWillReceiveProps (only called if parent updated)
        - shouldComponentUpdate
          - componentWillUpdate
            - render
            - [children's constructors or receive props phases]
          - componentDidUpdate
```

As you can see `App.render` is called before rendering children copmonents.

If you want to manipulate DOM manually for some reason, `componentWillUpdate` is not the right place to do it. Use `componentDidUpdate` after every update or `componentDidMount` after the initial render. Children's `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidMount` are triggered before the parent's lifecycle methods.